# Cannot run script as root, but permission denied in process without it

Tags: bash, root

I am attempting to install Mycroft AI on my Ubuntu machine.

If I run: `bash dev_setup.sh` I get the error: fatal: Unable to create '/home/bobo/mycroft-core/.git/index.lock': Permission denied

If I run `sudo bash dev_setup.sh`, I receive the message: This script should not be run as root or with sudo.
If you really need to for this, rerun with --allow-root

If I run `bash dev_setup.sh --allow-root`, I receive the same Permission denied error message

Any suggestions on how to get this to run

Edit:

Step previous to the problem:

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/MycroftAI/mycroft-core.git
Cloning into 'mycroft-core'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 552097, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (90/90), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (59/59), done.
remote: Total 552097 (delta 43), reused 64 (delta 31), pack-reused 552007
Receiving objects: 100% (552097/552097), 115.56
Resolving deltas: 100% (542625/542625), done.
```

Comment: Then create the directory and give permissions to it.

Comment: Sounds like you messed up the the [step before](https://mycroft-ai.gitbook.io/docs/using-mycroft-ai/get-mycroft/linux#getting-started). What happened during the `git clone ...`?

Comment: updated post to include previous step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need use sudo when execute:

```sh
sudo git clone https://github.com/MycroftAI/mycroft-core.git
```

When you do this, the directory is created with root's permissions and when try to execute the script bash dev_setup.sh requires root's permissions, but the script doesn't need those privileges, you need delete the directory and try again to execute git clone. Then you can execute the script.

```sh
# delete the directory
sudo rm -R mycroft-core
# clone again the repository
git clone https://github.com/MycroftAI/mycroft-core.git
# Move to the directory
cd mycroft-core
# Execute the script
bash dev_setup.sh
```

Comment: Thank you, yes. my mistake and now fixed.